# ASP.NET Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webforms application and trying to implement jQuery autocomplate on a text box. The server code is getting called, but nothing is displayed. I've replaced the call to the web service and added some static text and that gets displayed OK. Can anyone see what the issue is?

The server side code is here:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string[] ReturnPostcodes(string term)
    {
        PostcodeService postcodes = new PostcodeService();
        var results = postcodes.ReturnPostcodes().Where(p => p.Postcode.StartsWith(term.ToUpper())).Select(p => p.Postcode).Take(20).ToArray();
        return results;

    }
```

The HTML is here:

```
<tr>
        <td>Mobile Telephone:</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPostcode"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
```

The jquery is here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_mainContent_txtPostcode').each(function () {

            $(this).autocomplete({
                 source: '/Postcodes.asmx/ReturnPostcodes'
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: This link should help you. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason nothing is showing up is because you are not giving autocomplete the correct data format, also you are not specifying it how to load the data.
You can return JSON or XML format from webservice or parse the response yourself using jquery. Checkout [jquery ui autocomplete site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) for **Remote JSONP** and **XML data parsed once** examples.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Result` is not empty

Try using StartsWith and pass in a StringComparison

```
  var results = postcodes.ReturnPostcodes().Where(p => p.Postcode.StartsWith(term,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(p => p.Postcode).Take(20).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

asp.net WebMethods returns a json object containing the response in a 'd' variable (and there's some options to set when you call it with jQuery XHR), 
script snippet:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var lastXhr, cache = {};

            $('#<%= Search.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var term = request.term;
                    if (term in cache) {
                        response(cache[term]);
                        return;
                    }

                    lastXhr = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetBooks",
                        data: "{ \"term\": \"" + request.term + "\" }",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            cache[term] = data.d;
                            if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                                response(data.d);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```